# Jquery .Stop() slowdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/332tS/
When Using ".stop()" in Jquery, is it possible to make it slow to a halt THEN continue? instead of stopping on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...if you want to halt and then continue

```
$("#navbar #home .inverted").stop(true,false).animate({"width":"0px"}, 500);
```

or you can refer this too
[try this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/)

Comment: Trying now, sorry no-one answered for a while and i decided to go to bed

Comment: I want it to slow down then go back to 0